# this.prop is not getting though right

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple todo app to practise my react skills. I have 3 components, which I will show you below.

The issue is that my prop is not getting trough right because it is not recognized only when the `onChange` method set the `State` I will show you:

Here is my AddTodoComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../App.css';
import update from 'react-addons-update';

import TodoItemComponent from '../TodoItemComponent/TodoItemComponent';

class AddTodoComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todo: '',
            todoArray: []
        };
    }

    addTodo(e){
        console.log('e', e.target.value, 'todoArray', this.state.todoArray);
        this.state.todoArray.push(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ todo: this.state.todo });

        // this.state.todoArray.push(<TodoItemComponent todo={this.state.todo} onDelete={this.delete}></TodoItemComponent>);
    }

    delete(index){
        console.log('thisIndex', index);

        this.setState({
            todoArray: update(this.state.todoArray, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
        });
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (            
            <div>
                <div className="input-group m-b-md">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Todo..." value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-react" type="button" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)}> Add</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.todoArray.map((todo, index) => (
                       <TodoItemComponent todo={this.state.todo} key={index} onDelete={this.delete.bind(this, index)}></TodoItemComponent>
                    ))} 
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTodoComponent;
```

And here is the TodoItemComponent.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../App.css';

class TodoItemComponent extends Component {
  deleteTodo(todo){
      console.log('deleteTodo', this.props.todo);
      this.props.onDelete(this.props.todo);
  }

  render() {
      console.log('this.props.todo', this.props.todo);

    return (
        <div>            
            <li className="list-group-item todo-item">
                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-md">
                    <span className="fa fa-check"></span>
                </button>
                {this.props.todo}
                <span className="pull-right">
                    <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-xs">
                        <span className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle" onClick={() => this.deleteTodo(this.props.todo)}>
                        <span className="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </li>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItemComponent;
```

And here `this.props.todo` gives me no response at all.. I want the value of the input field to pass trough to the `TodoItemComponent` to show up when I click add.

Comment: Minimal, working example would be helpful. Code snippet or codesandbox :)

Comment: @Kinduser do you maybe have a working react.jsx snippet?

Comment: Codesandbox has a set environment, ready to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call super(props) in constructor and in addTodo(e) function change `this.setState({ todo: this.state.todo })` to

```
const todos this.state.todoArray.slice();
todos.push(e.target.value); // this will insert the button state
this.setState({ todoArray: todos });
```

And In render
instead of

```
{this.state.todoArray.map((todo, index) => (
    <TodoItemComponent todo={this.state.todo} key={index} onDelete={this.delete.bind(this, index)}></TodoItemComponent>
                    ))}
```

do this

```
{this.state.todoArray.map((todo, index) => (
    <TodoItemComponent todo key={index} onDelete={this.delete.bind(this, index)}></TodoItemComponent>
                    ))}
```

**Update:**
instead of     `todos.push(e.target.value);` do     `todos.push(this.state.todo);` in addTodo()

Comment: This returns true in the prop in the `TodoItemComponent` instead of the value of the input

Comment: So `addTodo()` looks like this: `    addTodo(e){
        const todos = this.state.todoArray.slice();
        todos.push(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ todoArray: todos });
    }`

Comment: sorry e.target.value will give button state. I have updated the answer

Comment: In `AddTodoComponent` the todos log the value, but in `TodoItemComponent` if I log the `props` than it returns me: `props Object {todo: true, onDelete: function}`

Comment: I edited your answer it does work with the change thanks! Could you maybe explain why you do this in the `addTodo()` like firnst slice the array.

Comment: So as you want to keep the todo some where hence keeping them in state make sense and if I have done `this.state.todoArray.push(this.state.todo)` then the Component will not update because it need to be notified to do so I have done this.setState. Now you may ask why slice cann't we simply so `this.setState({ todoArray: this.state.todoArray });`. Answer to this question is https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c (never mutate state)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call super(props) in constructor.

Source :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Class components should always call the base constructor with props.

Hope this helps.

Hi, I don't have enough credit to comment, You need to change your code like this:

```
class TodoItemComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
   }

deleteTodo(todo){
  console.log('deleteTodo', this.props.todo);
  this.props.onDelete(this.props.todo);
}
render() {
  console.log('this.props.todo', this.props.todo);
return (
    <div>            
        <li className="list-group-item todo-item">
            <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-md">
                <span className="fa fa-check"></span>
            </button>
            {this.props.todo}
            <span className="pull-right">
                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-xs">
                    <span className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
                </button>

                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle" onClick={() => this.deleteTodo(this.props.todo)}>
                    <span className="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </div>
);
}}
```

Comment: Thats what I am doing in the `AddTodoComponent` and than passing it as prop to `TodoItemComponent` do I also have to call super(props) there?

Comment: If I do this it recognize the prop but when I added an other todo the previous added todo will also change to the second added value.

Comment: problem is with this line : this.setState({ todo: this.state.todo });

Comment: How do I fix this? `setState({ value: this.state.todo})` something like this set a new prop?